# Does Gatsby's createPages API send the path to the template?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

I've been following this Gatsby tutorial to create pages dynamically based on my CMS's creation of markdown files: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/

I don't understand how the GraphQL query in the file **blogTemplate.js** receives the `$path` variable. I can see that the createPages function in **gatsby-node.js** creates the page based off the result of its own GraphQL query, and uses the 'path' frontmatter element to choose the URL for the created page.

However, how does that created page know its own path? The query called **pageQuery** in the tutorial uses the `$path` variable to source its own data, but I can't see how it receives that variable. Thank you in advance for any explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While creating the pages, we can pass context,
`All context values are made available to a template’s GraphQL queries as arguments prefaced with $`

```
     exports.createPages = async function ({ actions, graphql }) {
  const { data } = await graphql(`
    query {
      allMarkdownRemark {
        edges {
          node {
            fields {
              slug
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(edge => {
    const slug = edge.node.fields.slug
    actions.createPage({
      path: slug,
      component: require.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: { path: slug }, //here you can pass path through context parameter, the slug can be then accesed under $path variable in the template
    })
  })
}
`
```

using $ sign we can then access the path value in template side

```
  export const query = graphql`
  query($path: String!) {
    ...
  }
`
```

Comment: Thank you for the help so far: I understand that the gatsby-node.js createPages function uses the query you’ve written, but my question is about the query on the blogTemplate.js file. How does that query (called ‘pageQuery’ in the docs) get the $page variable?

Comment: for that, I will post an answer

Answer (score 0):

Graphql uses redux internall and all information regarding pages creation and paths are updated to gatsby's redux store and from thereon the graphql query is executed for each page

Now according to [gatsby `createPage` github code comment](http://Data%20in%20%22context%22%20is%20passed%20to%20GraphQL%20as%20potential%20arguments%20when%20running%20the)

> Data in "context" is passed to GraphQL as potential arguments when
>   running the page query.
>
> When arguments for `GraphQL` are constructed, the `context` object is
>   combined with the page object so *both* page object and context data
>   are available as arguments. So you don't need to add the page "`path`"
>   to the context as it's already available in GraphQL. If a context
>   field duplicates a field already used by the page object, this can
>   break functionality within Gatsby so must be avoided.